"If John bought food, Mary would cook dinner." — Why is this a counterfactual conditional? The fact that John will buy food or not is unestablished
A Concise Introduction to Logic by Patrick J. Hurley, page 332:

Subjunctive conditionals are often called counterfactual conditionals because their antecedents are typically false.

terminology from the book above:
In if A, (then) B or B, if A, A is called an antecedent and B a consequent.

examples from the internet:
(1) If kangaroos had no tails, they would topple over.
(2) If Peter believed in ghosts, he would be afraid to be here.
(3) If I were Bill Gates, then I would be rich.
(4) If dolphins were fish, then they would be cold blooded.
(5) What if Kennedy had not been assassinated?
As far as I understood, (1-5) all consist of counterfactual conditionals because the antecedents in them are false since the statements in their if-clauses are not true.

my examples:
(6a) If John bought food, Mary would cook dinner. — "Bought" is in the subjunctive mood.
(6b) If John buys food, Mary will cook dinner. — "Buys" is in the indicative mood.
my logic:
In both (6a) and (6b), we don't know whether John will buy food or not.
That is, we don't know whether the fact that John will buy food is true or false.
So we can't state the antecedents in (6a) and (6b) are false.
Therefore, the subjunctive conditional in (6a) is not counterfactual.
For some reason (I don't know why), it seems to me I'm not right about (6a) and it also belongs to counterfactual conditionals.
So I have some questions:
Why is my logic about (6a) incorrect?
Why is (6a) also a counterfactual conditional?
